# How can I run Android tests with sbt?

Tags: android, scala, junit, sbt, sbt-android-plugin

I developed for my application a small suite of Android tests written in Scala that uses the Robotium library. The suite is for all intents and purposes a standard Android JUnit test project and runs successfully if launched from Eclipse.

I've already successfully built and run my main Android application with sbt android-plugin.  The main application is located in `[ProjectDir]/src/main`.  I was also able to successfully [build my Android test application](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin/wiki/Building-Android-Test-Projects) that is located in the `[ProjectDir]/tests/src/main` directory.  I checked the emulator, and the test application appears to have been correctly installed with android-plugin's `tests/android:install-emulator` command.  However, when I try to run the test project via `sbt tests/android:test-emulator`, I get:

```
...
Test results for InstrumentationTestRunner=
Time: 0.001

OK (0 tests)
```

How I can get sbt android-plugin to recognize that the project contains JUnit tests and run them?

Answer (score 1):

The naming convention used here is the same as the normal JUnit and as such you need to name the tests xxxTest.class. They also need to extend TestCase (AndroidTestCase, InstrumentationTestCase etc...).

To reiterate, eclipse will run a command which will look like:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.android.foo.FooTest,com.android.foo.TooTest com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

It will append the classes name to the command so naming convention might not apply.

If you run from sbt, it will run

```
adb shell am instrument -w com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

which will find all the classes under the package name of the application com.android.foo which finishes with someClassNameTest.

Comment: So are you saying that it works for you?  These are tests that run fine unchanged inside Eclipse's Junit Android test runner.  I am unaware of a class naming convention, but am aware of a method naming convention--that they method names need to be preceded by the word "test".  My tests extend a custom class `TestFixture` which extends `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`.